# Why does reversing my linkedlist not work as expected?

Tags: java

Below is linked list program, I am trying to reverse the linked list by k- nodes. k is the input provided by the user. But the issue is below logic only returns first three nodes in reverse order.

```
package p;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListDemoReverseKNode {

    class MyList {

        public int info;
        public MyList link;
        public MyList(){
            this.link = null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyList s = new MyList();
        System.out.println("enter value  :");
        s.info = sc.nextInt();
        Character ch = null;

        MyList t = s;

        MyList commonNode = null;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("to create node press Y else N ");
            ch = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N') {
                break;
            }

            s.link = new MyList();
            System.out.println("enter value for the node :");
            s.link.info = sc.nextInt();
            s = s.link;

        }

        // Reverse the linked list k-node :
        s = t;
        LinkedListDemoReverseKNode linkedListDemo3 = new LinkedListDemoReverseKNode();
        MyList head = linkedListDemo3.reverseLinkedListKNode(s, 3);
        while (head != null) {
            System.out.println("info :: " + head.info);
            head = head.link;
        }

    }

    private MyList reverseLinkedListKNode(MyList head, int k) {

        MyList s = head;
        MyList prev = null;
        MyList next = null;
        int count = 0;
        while (count < k && s != null) {
            next = s.link;
            s.link = prev;
            prev = s;
            s = next;
            count++;
        }

        if (next != null)
            s.link = reverseLinkedListKNode(next, k);


        return prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of your post is–by far–the most important decision you’ll make :)

Comment: That is perhaps because you are passing 3 to reverseLinkedListKNode(MyList head, int k)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Reverse the linked list k-node :
    s = t;
    LinkedListDemoReverseKNode linkedListDemo3 = new LinkedListDemoReverseKNode();
    MyList head = linkedListDemo3.reverseLinkedListKNode(s, 3);
    while (head != null) {
        System.out.println("info :: " + head.info);
        head = head.link;
```

In this line of code where it says:
    MyList head = linkedlistDemo3.reverselinkedlistNode(s,3)
Try changing where it says (s, 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this part of your code `MyList head = linkedListDemo3.reverseLinkedListKNode(s, 3);` you are telling it to reverse the three first nodes in your linked list.

The method asks for number of `k` nodes to be reversed:

```
private MyList reverseLinkedListKNode(MyList head, int k)
```

You could set `k` to the total nodes in the list to reverse all nodes, or to any number of nodes to reverse.

Good luck.

Comment: My Ask is if the if k = 3  and the list contains 10-> 20 -> 30 -> 40 , then output will be 30 -> 20 -> 10 -> 40

Comment: My Ask is if the if k = 3  and the list contains 10-> 20 -> 30 -> 40 , then output will be 30 -> 20 -> 10 -> 40

Comment: @Vikasnaik That behavior is correct? It is what the code does.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use Collections.reverse...

Comment: `LinkedListDemoReverseKNode` is not a Collection

Comment: Sorry, the title and the class name let think that it is a LinkedList

Comment: Simply using Collections.reverse, you will not get qualified in the interview.

Comment: Which interview? Anyway, with the current title, this question will drag people wanting to reverse a LinkedList, so I will let this answer for them.